# Python KNN weighting during .predict()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I'm using a KNN algorithm for a class (instructed to use this algorithm, may not what you'd expect for application, see below)

Essentially, we have a raspberry pi set up to collect the signal strengths of 6 local WIFI router Mac addresses. At different locations on a floor of our building we've recorded these signal strengths in .csv files.

Using python I've created a script which uses the functions on this page. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html

I fit a knn as below:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1, algorithm = 'auto')
knn.fit(strengths, labels)
```

where strengths is a nested array like this:

```
[[Loc1strengths],[Loc2strengths],[Loc3strengths],[Loc4strengths],[Loc5strengths],[Loc6strengths]]
```

labels is set up like this:

```
[Loc1, Loc2, Loc3, Loc4, Loc5, Loc6]
```

Later in the script, I collect the signal strengths of the 6 local WIFI router Mac addresses and try to predict the location of my pi using knn.predict() and hope to get the location of the pi, Location1 for example.

The results aren't great, it does a relatively poor job of figuring out where it is.

I was wondering if there was a way to weight the function of knn.predict() so that the neighbors of the most recent location are weighted more heavily, the pi won't move to the other side of the floor without crossing the other points.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want to add a time element to the KNN model?

Comment: Not so much time, I have the my script doing a knn.predict() every 2 seconds. 

I would like it to weight more heavily certain outcomes based on the most recent outcome.

Comment: That is in the area time-series forecasting.

Comment: I know you are asking about KNN, but could you use another classifier? Maybe `LogisitcRegression`?

Comment: @KPLauritzen wouldn't that be good for predicting a dichotomous dependent variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit hacky, but you can do this using the `weights` parameter in `KNeighborsClassifier`. If you add your times as an extra feature and then write a custom distance function you can weight the distance between samples using time. A really simple example shown here:

```
def time_weight(x1, x2):
    # I've added my time variable at the end of my features        
    time_diff = np.linalg.norm(x1[-1] - x2[-1])
    feature_diff = np.linalg.norm(x1[:-1]-x2[:-1])
    return time_diff*feature_diff
```

Some dummy data

```
X = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 0.5]])
time = np.array([0, 5]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0, 1])
X_with_time = np.hstack((X, time))
```

Test that our weighted distance makes sense:

```
print(time_weight(np.array([0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0.75, 2])))
print(time_weight(np.array([0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0.75, 3])))
print(time_weight(np.array([0, 0.5, 5]), np.array([0, 0.75, 2])))
print(time_weight(np.array([0, 0.5, 5]), np.array([0, 0.75, 3])))
```

**Output:**

```
0.5
0.75
0.75
0.5
```

That's what I expect to see, if something is twice as far away in time, it is twice the distance. So now check it works with `KNeighborsClassifier`

```
X_with_time = np.hstack((X, time))
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(metric=time_weight, n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_with_time, y)
print(knn.predict([[0, 0.75, 2]]))
print(knn.predict([[0, 0.75, 3]]))
```

**Output:**

```
[0]
[1]
```

Again that's what I expected to see. So looks like it's not too painful to do. I would recommend spending some time thinking about how you want to set up your distance function, as this will really affect the results.